# Web Site (ASP.NET) Deployment with SQL 2008

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-hosting, sql-server-2008-express

I have a website built with ASP.NET and uses SQL Server 2008 (Express edition).
I have a group of testers in different locations. I would like to host the web site on a web server.

1. What are my options to get a free or low cost web hosting service?
2. If I do use a web hosting service, will I be sharing the SQL server?
3. My application uses SQL database heavily, will I see a performance hit?
4. My client is currently setting up their web server - what information should I collect from them to check if my app can be hosted on their web server?
5. Can I load SQL Server 2008 - Express edition on the web server or do I have to get them to purchase SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Go to your previous questions. Select the most useful answer and check with big check left from it.

Comment: What means 'heavily' - performance/storage wise? Remember that SQLExpress2008 has 10GB limit http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx among other important limitations.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use your server or use some hosting provider, according to you financial needs and goals. This is very broad question, and try to solve it by yourself.
2. When you use the web hosting service, hosting server must see your SQL server - otherwise it coundn't get the data from it.
3. Performance will be depend on quality of your application. If it is not good written, then you will suffer from poor performance. Test it!
4. Are there any support for the .NET, ASP.NET and SQL Server Express according to your application.
5. Yes, you can, after installing it on their server.